# How to create Connection Snackbar with toast like Skype on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I used this code for check connection, Now I use showDialog. How to create like Skype connection snack bar with toast?
like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjeZE.jpg

```
try{
final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
if(result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty){
 showDialog(...)
}else{
 showDialog(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from the [flutter toast](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluttertoast) package which will enable you to create the `connecting..` toast. As for the `SnackBar` you can call it using `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar()`.

I have added this picture from the Flutter toast package examples

[image: Toast demonstration]